OnePlus Pad 2 Stylo 2 vibration motor in app
I am currently working on a note-taking app for android (14+), specifically for my OnePlus Pad 2. OnePlus has a really good stylus (stylo 2), that has a haptic motor inside the stylus (not in the tablet!), which "simulates" the vibrations caused by a pen on paper, which for me works really well....
Besides the oneplus-notes app and hiPaint I couldn't find any app that supports said feature, thus I dabbled around in kotlin/java with a lot of help from chat-gpt/gemini, however these two seem unable to find a way to get the stylus-vibration to work.
SO far, I tried android's implemented "vibrate", however this seems to only cover devices, not styluses.
Unfortunately I do not have another tab to check it...
Can anyone,by chance outline a way to get the oneplus stylus to vibrate? :-D
edit: upon checking reddit, I discovered that hipaint works fully with the stylus and my logcat | grep hipaint when drawing in hipaint returns the following:
12-23 07:15:22.644  3558  3727 I WakeLockCheck: getAllTopPkgName: listTopPkg=[com.aige.hipaint], listTopPkgTmp=[OplusAppInfo{windowingMode=1, activityType=1, taskId=3389, appBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 3000, 2120), appInfo=ApplicationInfo{a98559 com.aige.hipaint}, topActivity=ComponentInfo{com.aige.hipaint/com.aige.hipaint.draw.ui.DrawMainUI}, displayId=0, orientation=2, userId=0, launchedFromPackage=com.aige.hipaint, isRootActivity=false, extension=Bundle[{isTaskEmbedded=false, launchScenario=0, flexible_split_support_multi_instance=false, isContainerTask=false, getRootActivity=ComponentInfo{com.aige.hipaint/com.aige.hipaint.inkpaint.login.activity.TabActivity}}]}]
12-23 07:15:51.413  3558  3675 D OplusSplitScreenManagerService: com.aige.hipaint supportsSplitScreen by forceResizable activity return:true
12-23 07:15:51.951  3558  3675 D OplusSplitScreenManagerService: com.aige.hipaint supportsSplitScreen by forceResizable activity return:true
12-23 07:15:51.955  3558  3675 D OplusSplitScreenManagerService: com.aige.hipaint supportsSplitScreen by forceResizable activity return:true
12-23 07:15:52.039  4712  5056 I VideoScene: updateVideoPlayInfo : playing = true uid = 10379 pkg = com.aige.hipaint
12-23 07:15:52.040  4712  5056 I VideoCallScene: updateVideoPlayInfo : playing = true uid = 10379 pkg = com.aige.hipaint
12-23 07:15:52.662 25506 12816 W LOG_FLOWCTRL: ==LOGS OVER PROC QUOTA(300), rows(521) bytes(35438) com.aige.hipaint:draw DROPPED==
12-23 07:15:53.040  4712  5056 I VoiceCallScene: MSG_CHK_VIDEO_STATE : uid = 10379, pkg = com.aige.hipaint, mVoiceCallUid = 10124, mVoiceCallPkg = com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
12-23 07:15:55.059 25506 25512 I ge.hipaint:draw: ThreadFlipBegin blocked for 17.697ms
12-23 07:15:55.129  4712  5056 I VideoScene: updateVideoPlayInfo : playing = false uid = 10379 pkg = com.aige.hipaint
12-23 07:15:55.130  4712  5056 I VideoCallScene: updateVideoPlayInfo : playing = false uid = 10379 pkg = com.aige.hipaint
12-23 07:15:56.130  4712  5056 I VoiceCallScene: MSG_CHK_VIDEO_STATE : uid = 10379, pkg = com.aige.hipaint, mVoiceCallUid = 10124, mVoiceCallPkg = com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
12-23 07:16:00.016  3558  3697 D OomAdjusterSocExtImpl: App adj change from previous state to cached state : 25354 com.aige.hipaint

edit 2:
logcat |grep oplus_bt* 

12-23 07:17:58.235  4817  4817 I oplus_bt_dual_sync: stack_down_sync_action: type=18, len=17
12-23 07:17:58.235  4817  4817 I oplus_bt_qos_monitor: get_oplus_qos_data getting qos data
12-23 07:17:59.587  4817  5154 I oplus_bt_stack_ble_event: report_stack_ble_last_data_transfer, f8:**:**:**:04:2d
12-23 07:17:59.799  4817  5154 I oplus_bt_stack_ble_event: report_stack_ble_last_data_transfer, f8:**:**:**:04:2d
12-23 07:18:03.434  4817  5154 I oplus_bt_stack_ble_event: report_stack_ble_last_data_transfer, f8:**:**:**:04:2d
12-23 07:18:04.226  4817  4817 I oplus_bt_dual_sync: stack_down_sync_action: type=18, len=17
12-23 07:18:04.226  4817  4817 I oplus_bt_qos_monitor: get_oplus_qos_data getting qos data
12-23 07:18:10.234  4817  4817 I oplus_bt_dual_sync: stack_down_sync_action: type=18, len=17
12-23 07:18:10.234  4817  4817 I oplus_bt_qos_monitor: get_oplus_qos_data getting qos data
12-23 07:18:16.229  4817  4817 I oplus_bt_dual_sync: stack_down_sync_action: type=18, len=17
12-23 07:18:16.229  4817  4817 I oplus_bt_qos_monitor: get_oplus_qos_data getting qos data
12-23 07:18:17.199  4817  5154 I oplus_bt_stack_ble_event: report_stack_ble_last_data_transfer, f8:**:**:**:04:2d
12-23 07:18:17.209  4817  5154 I oplus_bt_stack_ble_event: report_stack_ble_last_data_transfer, f8:**:**:**:04:2d
12-23 07:18:22.220  4817  4817 I oplus_bt_dual_sync: stack_down_sync_action: type=18, len=17
12-23 07:18:22.221  4817  4817 I oplus_bt_qos_monitor: get_oplus_qos_data getting qos data
12-23 07:18:22.856  4817  5154 I oplus_bt_stack_ble_event: report_stack_ble_last_data_transfer, f8:**:**:**:04:2d
12-23 07:18:23.073  4817  5154 I oplus_bt_stack_ble_event: report_stack_ble_last_data_transfer, f8:**:**:**:04:2d
12-23 07:18:26.485  4817  5154 I oplus_bt_stack_ble_event: report_stack_ble_last_data_transfer, f8:**:**:**:04:2d
12-23 07:18:28.235  4817  4817 I oplus_bt_dual_sync: stack_down_sync_action: type=18, len=17
12-23 07:18:28.235  4817  4817 I oplus_bt_qos_monitor: get_oplus_qos_data getting qos data
12-23 07:18:34.243  4817  4817 I oplus_bt_dual_sync: stack_down_sync_action: type=18, len=17
12-23 07:18:34.243  4817  4817 I oplus_bt_qos_monitor: get_oplus_qos_data getting qos data
12-23 07:18:38.035  4817  5154 I oplus_bt_stack_ble_event: report_stack_ble_last_data_transfer, f8:**:**:**:04:2d
12-23 07:18:38.047  4817  5154 I oplus_bt_stack_ble_event: report_stack_ble_last_data_transfer, f8:**:**:**:04:2d
12-23 07:18:40.243  4817  4817 I oplus_bt_dual_sync: stack_down_sync_action: type=18, len=17
12-23 07:18:40.244  4817  4817 I oplus_bt_qos_monitor: get_oplus_qos_data getting qos data
12-23 07:18:40.630  4817  5154 I oplus_bt_stack_ble_event: report_stack_ble_last_data_transfer, f8:**:**:**:04:2d
12-23 07:18:40.844  4817  5154 I oplus_bt_stack_ble_event: report_stack_ble_last_data_transfer, f8:**:**:**:04:2d
12-23 07:18:42.457  4817  5154 I oplus_bt_stack_ble_event: report_stack_ble_last_data_transfer, f8:**:**:**:04:2d
12-23 07:18:46.246  4817  4817 I oplus_bt_dual_sync: stack_down_sync_action: type=18, len=17
12-23 07:18:46.246  4817  4817 I oplus_bt_qos_monitor: get_oplus_qos_data getting qos data
12-23 07:18:52.247  4817  4817 I oplus_bt_dual_sync: stack_down_sync_action: type=18, len=17
12-23 07:18:52.247  4817  4817 I oplus_bt_qos_monitor: get_oplus_qos_data getting qos data
12-23 07:18:58.248  4817  4817 I oplus_bt_dual_sync: stack_down_sync_action: type=18, len=17
12-23 07:18:58.248  4817  4817 I oplus_bt_qos_monitor: get_oplus_qos_data getting qos data


There's no public API unfortunately and in addition they locked it only to the system apps by requiring some extra permissions, you can check more here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/oneplus/comments/1fcwytz/comment/lyadtht/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button

sad, that's where I came from ...
I also already tried logcat for hiPaint, as one user mentions that app works:
https://www.reddit.com/r/oneplus/comments/1fcwytz/comment/m3d5xnm/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button
I will update the post, in case it turns out helful to someone :-)
